# how to force column to rownames in multiple split dataframes then apply a function over all dataframes (of unequal lengths)?

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation

I am trying to force column to rownames in multiple split dataframes then apply a function over all dataframes? (unequal lengths) I get the error that is embedded in the code below. Can I work past this?

```
# sample dataset below

ID <- c("SB1","SB2","SB3","SB4","SB1","SB1","SB2","SB4","SB2", "SB1")
z <- c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","D")
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:10
n <- max(length(x), length(y))
year <- c(1999,1999,1999,1999,2000,2001,2000,2001,2001,2002)
length(x) <- n                      
length(y) <- n
length(z) <- n
length(year) <- n
sitebyspec <- cbind(ID,x,y,z,year)
sitebyspec <- as.data.frame(sitebyspec)


# my process (split df by year, force ID column to rownames)
sitebyspec.split <- split(sitebyspec, (sitebyspec$year)) # split based on season
as.data.frame(sitebyspec.split) %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="ID")
    ## Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 2, 3, 1

# my next step if this worked ... 
sitebyspec.split %>%
  sitebyspec.split[,c(1:3)] %>%
  map(~ contribdiv(., "richness")) %>%
  map(summary)
```

Can I integrate the column to rownames into this last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R's `by`. Unlike `split`, you can pass a function directly on the subsetted dataframes:

```
proc_df <- function(df) df %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var="ID")

df_list <- by(sitebyspec, sitebyspec$year, proc_df)

df_list
# sitebyspec$year: 1999
#     x y z year
# SB1 1 1 A 1999
# SB2 2 2 B 1999
# SB3 1 3 C 1999
# SB4 2 4 D 1999
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# sitebyspec$year: 2000
#     x y z year
# SB1 1 5 E 2000
# SB2 1 7 B 2000
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# sitebyspec$year: 2001
#     x y z year
# SB1 2 6 A 2001
# SB4 2 8 C 2001
# SB2 1 9 D 2001
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# sitebyspec$year: 2002
#     x  y z year
# SB1 2 10 D 2002
```

And for extended function,

```
proc_df <- function(df) {
    tryCatch({df %>% 
               remove_rownames %>% 
               column_to_rownames(var="ID") %>%
               select(1:2) %>%
               contribdiv(., "richness")
             }, error = function(e) NA)
}

df_list <- by(sitebyspec, sitebyspec$year, proc_df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! This is an interesting way of getting this done - hadn't seen this before. When I do this on my actual data, I get the error "Error in rowSums(comm) : 'x' must be numeric". The columns are all numeric. any idea what the problem could be here?

Comment: Not sure why that's happening until I see full data. Does above work on posted sample? If so, then it is a data issue with actual data.

Comment: Hello, no the code does not work on the sample data.

Comment: See update wrapping call in `tryCatch` where any errors returns `NA` in list. Possibly one of the *year* groups cannot be run in `contribdiv`.

Comment: I'm getting this to work now, but an error keeps getting thrown at the last step (mapping step). Error in min(which(comm[, i] == 1)):max(which(comm[, i] == 1)) : 
  result would be too long a vector

Comment: What mapping step? No error should be thrown if using `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 3):

With modified data (see below) here's a solution.

Possibly the main problem lies within your data. As provided, there are lots of NAs in your `x` column, where I assume `x` should have recycled itself. Then `vegan::contribdiv()` wants at least two dimensions and you only provide one row in your data. Besides, it needs numeric and can only be applied to columns `1:2`. In your code with `as.data.frame(sitebyspec.split)`, you're trying to turn a list into a dataframe, which I don't think you want to and results in the error.

First, use `lapply()` to transform the `ID` column into rownames.

```
sitebyspec.split <- lapply(sitebyspec.split, function(x) "rownames<-"(x, x[, 1])[, -1])
```

Second, use `lapply()` to apply your function to the list.

```
library(vegan)
sitebyspec.result <- lapply(sitebyspec.split, function(x) contribdiv(x[, 1:2], "richness"))
```

***Result***

```
> sitebyspec.result
$`1999`
        alpha beta     gamma
SB1 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
SB2 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
SB3 0.6666667    0 0.6666667

$`2000`
    alpha beta gamma
SB4     1    0     1
SB1     1    0     1

$`2001`
        alpha beta     gamma
SB1 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
SB2 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
SB4 0.6666667    0 0.6666667

$`2002`
    alpha beta gamma
SB2     1    0     1
SB1     1    0     1
```

***Data***

```
sitebyspec <- data.frame(ID=c("SB1", "SB2", "SB3", "SB4", "SB1", "SB1", "SB2", "SB4", "SB2", "SB1"), 
                         x=1:2, 
                         y=1:10, 
                         z=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), 
                         year=c(1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002))
```

Comment: Meanwhile, `by` is roughly equivalent to `split` + `lapply`!

Answer (score 1):

As the object is a `list`, we can loop through the `list` with `map` and then apply the functions in the OP's post

```
sitebyspec.split %>% 
       map(~ .x %>% 
                remove_rownames %>% 
                column_to_rownames(var = "ID"))
#$`1999`
#    x y z year
#SB1 1 1 A 1999
#SB2 2 2 B 1999
#SB3 1 3 C 1999

#$`2000`
#    x y z year
#SB4 2 4 D 2000
#SB1 2 6 A 2000

#$`2001`
#    x y z year
#SB1 1 5 E 2001
#SB2 1 7 B 2001
#SB4 2 8 C 2001

#$`2002`
#    x  y z year
#SB2 1  9 D 2002
#SB1 2 10 D 2002
```

The `contribdv` function can be applied in the same chain

```
library(vegan)
sitebyspec.split %>% 
    map(~ .x %>% 
             remove_rownames %>% 
             column_to_rownames(var = "ID") %>% 
             select(1:2) %>% 
             contribdiv(., "richness"))
#$`1999`
#        alpha beta     gamma
#SB1 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
#SB2 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
#SB3 0.6666667    0 0.6666667

#$`2000`
#    alpha beta gamma
#SB4     1    0     1
#SB1     1    0     1

#$`2001`
#        alpha beta     gamma
#SB1 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
#SB2 0.6666667    0 0.6666667
#SB4 0.6666667    0 0.6666667

#$`2002`
#    alpha beta gamma
#SB2     1    0     1
#SB1     1    0     1
```

NOTE: OP created the 'x', 'y' columns as  `factor`s, instead it should be `numeric`

#### data

```
sitebyspec <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
 2L, 1L), .Label = c("SB1", "SB2", "SB3", "SB4"), class = "factor"), 
x = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), y = 1:10, 
z = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), year = c(1999, 1999, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002)), .Names = c("ID", 
 "x", "y", "z", "year"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```